# Struggling with the logic for GCD

Tags: assembly, mips

So I wrote this code trying to find the GCD of 3 numbers in MIPS.

```
li $s0, 1 

whileloop:
bgt $s0, $t0, exit 
bgt $s0, $t1, exit 
bgt $s0, $t2, exit 
    IF:
    div $s0, $t0 
    mfhi $s1 
    div $s0, $t1
    mfhi $s2 
    div $s0, $t2 
    mfhi $s3 
    bne $s1, $zero, else  
    bne $s2, $zero, else  
    bne $s3, $zero, else 
    addi $s0, $s0, 1 
    j if 

    else: 
    addi $s0, $s0, 1 
    j whileloop 


exit: 

    la $a0, answer 
     syscall 

     move $a0, $s0 
     li $v0, 1 
     syscall
```

My logic was that in the loop I would divide each number by a number initialized at 1. If all of three user inputted numbers ($t0, $t1, $t2) are divisible by that number than add one to that number and try again with the next highest number. The break of this loop should be if the divisor is ever equal to any of the numbers because then it obviously couldnt be the GCD if its any higher. My logic seems to be off though because the else statement would have to be to increment the divisor by 1 as well so no matter what I am going to wind up exiting at the lowest number of the three. Could anybody see a way to implement this logically?

Comment: You just need to remember the last number that divided all 3 inputs, and print that as the result.

Comment: Isn't `gcd(a,b,c)` just `gcd(a,gcd(b,c))`?

Comment: Yeah I think it is but I am not sure how I could implement that either

Comment: Have you looked at the Euclidean algorithm for greatest common denominator?